# OpenCL Eclipse Loading but not reading kernel file

Tags: c, eclipse, kernel, opencl

I have a problem. OpenCL is loading the kernel but giving garbage values. If I were to take a guess then it's not able to execute the kernel. The program is compiling but giving garbage values. All the library paths, include and library are correct. The program works in the lab. However it is not working in the laptop.
This is the main C file :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<CL/cl.h>

//Max source size of the kernel string
#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)

int main (void)
{
//create the two input vectors
int i;
int LIST_SIZE;
printf("Enter how many elements = ");
scanf("%d",&LIST_SIZE);
int *A = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);

//Initialize the input vector

for(i=0;i<LIST_SIZE;i++)
{
    A[i] = i;
}
int *B = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
for(i=0;i<LIST_SIZE;i++)
{
    B[i] = i+10;
}
//Load the kernel source code into the array source_str
FILE *fp;
char *source_str;
size_t source_size;
fp = fopen("5-1.cl","r");
if(!fp)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Failed to load kernel.\n");
    exit(1);
}
source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
source_size = fread(source_str,1,MAX_SOURCE_SIZE,fp);
fclose(fp);

//Get platform and device information
cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
cl_uint ret_num_devices;
cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1,&platform_id,&ret_num_platforms);
ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id,CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU,1,&device_id,&ret_num_devices);

//Create an OpenCL context
cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL,1,&device_id,NULL,NULL,&ret);

//Create a command queue
cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context,device_id,NULL,&ret);

//Create memory buffers on the device for each vector A,B,C
cl_mem a_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, LIST_SIZE*sizeof(int),NULL,&ret);
cl_mem b_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, LIST_SIZE*sizeof(int),NULL,&ret);
cl_mem c_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, LIST_SIZE*sizeof(int),NULL,&ret);

//Copy the lists A and B to their respective memory buffers
ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue,a_mem_obj,CL_TRUE,0,LIST_SIZE*sizeof(int),A,0,NULL,NULL);
ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue,b_mem_obj,CL_TRUE,0,LIST_SIZE*sizeof(int),B,0,NULL,NULL);

//Create a program from the kernel source
cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context,1,(const char**)&source_str,(const size_t *)&source_size,&ret);

//Build the program
ret = clBuildProgram(program,1,&device_id,NULL,NULL,NULL);

//Create the OpenCL Kernel Object
cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program,"vector_add",&ret);

//Set the arguments of the kernel
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel,0,sizeof(cl_mem),(void *)&a_mem_obj);
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel,1,sizeof(cl_mem),(void *)&b_mem_obj);
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel,2,sizeof(cl_mem),(void *)&c_mem_obj);

//Execute the OpenCL kernel on the array
size_t global_item_size = LIST_SIZE;
size_t local_item_size = 1;

//Execute the kernel on the device
cl_event event;
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue,kernel,1,NULL,&global_item_size,&local_item_size,0,NULL,NULL);
ret = clFinish(command_queue);

//Read the memory buffer in <c on the device to the local variable C
int *C = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, c_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, LIST_SIZE*sizeof(int),C,0,NULL,NULL);

//Display the result to the screen
for(i=0;i<LIST_SIZE;i++)
{
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n",A[i],B[i],C[i]);
}

//Clean UP
ret = clFlush(command_queue);
ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
ret = clReleaseMemObject(a_mem_obj);
ret = clReleaseMemObject(b_mem_obj);
ret = clReleaseMemObject(c_mem_obj);
ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
ret = clReleaseContext(context);

free(A);
free(B);
free(C);

return 0;
}
```

Here is the kernel code :-

```
__kernel void vector_add(__global int* A,__global int* B,__global int* C)
{
//Get the index of the current work item
int i = get_global_id(0);
//Do the operation
C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
```

If someone has faced a similar situation in the past and solved it please help.

Comment: Did you inspect the source in the debugger before calling clCreateProgramWithSource? What status code do you get back? What do you get with CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS from clGetProgramBuildInfo?

Comment: Do you mean the value of ret which is passed as a pointer in the last parameter when I call clCreateProgramWithSource?

Comment: It's giving CL_INVALID_DEVICE error when I try to create the context

Comment: According to the documentation, it returns CL_INVALID_DEVICE "if OpenCL devices listed in device_list are not in the list of devices associated with program". The error might be higher up in your code. I suggest checking the status return code from all APIs.